# List the changes in file

Tags: svn

I checked out the file with svn, now I want to find what changes another user did in a file. Please help me with a command

svn co http://Prog1/FileOp/

From FileOp directory only 1 file is changed since the last commit. I want to track those changes.

Comment: `svn diff` or `svn blame` should help here.

Comment: In addition to the comment before you could see the history with `svn log`